# Compact representation of a function

Tags: functions, notation

\begin{equation}
\Phi(i,j) = 
\begin{cases}
1, & \textrm{if } \sum_{f_k \in \mathcal{F}} x_k(i,j) > 0, \\
0, & \textrm{otherwise.} 
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\alpha = \sum_{(i,j) \in \mathcal{L}} \Phi(i,j)
\end{equation}

I need $\alpha$. Is it possible to write a compact expression $\alpha$ without explicitly defining $\Phi(i,j)$

**Edit**:

$\mathcal{L}$ is the set of links in a graph.
$x_k(i,j)$ denotes if a link is active for a particular flow $f_k \in \mathcal{F}$ where $\mathcal{F}$ is the set of all flows.
$x_k(i,j)$ can either be 0 (False) or 1 (True) denoting link $(i,j)$ is inactive or active. Thus, $\alpha$ can be at most $|\mathcal{L}|$.

Comment: More context required. Urgently. For one, it is not even clear that $\alpha$ is not infinite from the above. You can replace the $\Phi$ by indicator functions, with the condition as indicated in the definition of $\Phi$, but then that may not be satisfactory.

Comment: Please say what all your symbols mean too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing it would be the following $\alpha = \sum\limits_{(i,j) \in \mathcal{L}}(1-\prod \limits_{f_k \in \mathcal{F}}(1 - x_k(i,j))$.  Basically you use $\prod$ as big $\bigwedge$ and use subtraction from one as a not to create a $\bigvee$.